# Angular JS: "active" class on menu items created by a controller

Tags: angularjs

I'm using a JSON service to list menu items (links). When navigating the different routes/pages I want an "active" class added to the link that is currently active (i.e. the page the user is on).

**I've used this jsfiddle as a starting point:** http://jsfiddle.net/p3ZMR/4/

I've also found several answers here on stackoverflow, but all of them are similar to the solution above.

But, that solution doesn't work if the links are generated via ng-repeat:

```
  <ul class="main-menu">
    <li ng-repeat="page in pages">
      <a href="/#/{{page.id}}" active-link="active">{{page.name}}</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

It seems as if the directive is called before the controller adds the links.

Is there any way to get around this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to highlight a current menu item in AngularJS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12592472/how-to-highlight-a-current-menu-item-in-angularjs)

Comment: I don't think so. The solution there requires the links to be hard coded

Comment: Nope. You can just say `getClass('/#/' + page.id)` and it would not be hard coded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A staple programming concept is separation of concerns. I personally do not like to keep logic or comparisons in my views. I would prefer to keep business logic and comparisons in the javascript

HTML

```
<ul class="main-menu">
    <li ng-repeat="page in pages">
        <a ng-click="menu(page)" ng-class="{ active: isActive(page.url)>{{page.name}}</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Javascript

```
angular.module('link', [])

function myController($scope, $location){ 
    $scope.links = [
     { url: "one", name: "One"},
     { url: "two", name: "Two"},
     { url: "", name: "Three"}
    ];

    $scope.isActive = function (viewLocation) {
        var pattern = '/' + viewLocation,
            re = new RegExp(pattern);
        return re.test($location.path());
    };

    $scope.menu = function (location) {
        $location.path('/' + location.location);
    };
}
```

Answer (score 5):

HTML for repeating links

```
<div ng-app="link">
    <div data-ng-controller="myController">
        <a href="#/{{ link.url }}" data-ng-repeat="link in links" data-ng-class="(link.url == location.path() && 'active')">
            {{ link.name }}
        </a> 
    </div>
</div>
```

Javascript

```
angular.module('link', [])

function myController($scope, $location){
    $scope.location = $location;
     $scope.links = [
         { url: "one", name: "One"},
         { url: "two", name: "Two"},
         { url: "", name: "Three"}
    ];
}
```

This will produce links one/two/three with three being highlighted in the red color. Here's a jsfiddle: **http://jsfiddle.net/4mFYy/1/**

Comment: Your jsfiddle doesn't seem to be working. The "active" class only gets added on click? Try changing .active color to "green" and it only works on pageload.

Comment: It doesn't work because none of the route provider stuff is wired up. It was just a demo to show you how to achieve it.

Comment: Ah, I think I missed a couple of details when I tried it, for example my url's are /#/foo so I need to check location.path() exluding the "/" i.e `$location.path().replace("/", "");`. Gonna give it another go.

Comment: If that's the case, i would just modify links to include the / in the url.

Answer (score 2):

As the author of your starting point, I updated the fiddle, so it should work now for your dynamic urls :).

```
angular.module('link', []).
  directive('activeLink', ['$location', function(location) {
  return {
      restrict: 'A',
      link: function(scope, element, attrs, controller) {
          var clazz = attrs.activeLink;
          scope.location = location;
          scope.$watch('location.path()', function(newPath) {
              if (attrs.href.substring(1) === newPath) {  //<------ Here it is already interpolated
                element.addClass(clazz);
              } else {
                element.removeClass(clazz);
              }
          });
      }

  };

  }]).
  controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', function(scope) {
    scope.pages=[
       { url: "one", name: "One"},
       { url: "two", name: "Two"},
       { url: "three", name: "Three"},
       { url: "", name: "home"}
    ];
  }]);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/p3ZMR/59/

The problem is, that the directive is reading out the href attribute, before it gets interpolated. I just changed it in a way, that the href will get read out, after it is interpolated.

Answer (score 0):

Ng-class was made for this. Check out the comments on the angular docs page for ng-class as its not well documented.