# Why can't i acces $location.path() in my directive?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In my angular application I have a menu with a set of links, I have put the links in an angular directive  and I want to use the current location to decide if a link is active and then add a css class to it.

What I have done so far is this:
(stripped to the relevant stuff)

```
angular.module(‘myNavigation’).directive(‘navItem’, ['$location', function($location) {

    console.log($location.absUrl());
    console.log($location.path());

    return {
        restrict: ‘EA’,
        scope: true,
        link: function (scope) {
            isCurrentLink = angular.equals(scope.item.href,$location.absUrl());
        },
        template: ‘<a ng-href=”{{item.href}}” ng-class=”{active:isCurrentLink}”>{{item.name}}</a>”
}
}]);
```

This works fine, but only if I put complete urls in the data for my navigation including domainname etc.  But the url’s in the navigation data received by my directive do not contain domain name / protocol etc.

Then first console.log gives me the full URL but the second returns an empty string.
For some reason I cannot acces `$location.path()` in my directive. What am i doing wrong?

By the way i do have a path, my application is not on the default page in the root folder.

**UPDATE**

I just discovered that $location.path() returns the part of the url after the hash(#), I was expecting it to return the part of the url without protocol, servername and serverport.

So when i go to *https://stackoverflow.com/posts/25894149/*, I'd want to have *posts/25894149/*.

Can i use $location to achieve this?

Comment: Have you seen this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12592472/how-to-highlight-a-current-menu-item

Comment: I did now, but I don't see a solution there

Answer (score 1):

I found out that `$location` cannot give this information.

When you include `$window` instead, you can ask for `$window.location.pathname` which gave me exactly what I needed.

for example when you url is:
url: `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25894149/#something`

`$window.location.pathname` wil return */questions/25894149/*