# TypeError: "Cannot read property 'activeMenuTab' of undefined" in AngularJS routing

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In my application, I am getting this same error (TypeError: "Cannot read property 'activeMenuTab' of undefined") 3 times on browser console, although application is working very well.

Error refers to this line of code in controller:

```
$scope.$route = $route;
$scope.isSelected = function(menuTab) {
    return $route.current.activeMenuTab == menuTab;
};
```

I call this function from menu in View:

```
<ul>
<li><a href="#somePage" ng-class="{ active: isSelected('somePage') }">...</a></li>
.
.
.
</ul>
```

Does anybody know what to do with this error, please? I try my best to solve it, but as I can see, still not enough.

Comment: can try with `if (!angular.isUndefined($route.current)) {}`

Answer (score 0):

The error tell you that $route.current is undefined, so it canot access the property 'activeMenuTab'. You need to save in your controller scope "activeMenuTab".

Maybe you can take a look at this [How to highlight a current menu item?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12592472/how-to-highlight-a-current-menu-item)

for a better way?