# Highlight clicked hyperlink in angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

Below is my HTML code,

```
<div id="Navigation" class="md-dialog-full">
      <div class="products-options">
           <a ng-click='addType("Physical")' href="javascript:void(0);">
               <h1>Physical</h1>
               <label>An item that is shipped to your customers</label>
           </a>
           <a ng-click='addType("Digital")' href="javascript:void(0);">
               <h1>Digital</h1>
               <label>Content that is downloaded</label>
           </a>
           <a ng-click='addType("Service")' href="javascript:void(0);">
               <h1>Services</h1>
               <label>Provide a Service</label>
           </a>
      </div>
</div>
```

I want to highlight the selected hyperlink, I have tried many methods in internet but almost all are linked with the URL of the hyperlink. Please help. I have succeed in using hover to highlight when hovering over a link but I'm stuck in highlighting the clicked link.

Comment: similar to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12592472/how-to-highlight-a-current-menu-item

and check this http://codepen.io/SkiWether/pen/lzjAq

Comment: It has URL paths which my code does not have

Comment: i have given you refrence :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you say your code does not have url paths, I'm assuming that all of this needs to happen within the same view and the same controller. In that case, you can put a variable on the scope, say `selectedLink`, and use `ng-class` to apply the proper styling:

```
<div id="Navigation" class="md-dialog-full">
    <div class="products-options">
        <a ng-click='addType("Physical");selectedLink = "Physical"' href="javascript:void(0);" ng-class="{'selected': selectedLink === 'Physical'}">
            <h1>Physical</h1>
            <label>An item that is shipped to your customers</label>
        </a>
        <a ng-click='addType("Digital");selectedLink = "Digital"' href="javascript:void(0);" ng-class="{'selected': selectedLink === 'Digital'}">
            <h1>Digital</h1>
            <label>Content that is downloaded</label>
        </a>
        <a ng-click='addType("Service");selectedLink = "Service"' href="javascript:void(0);" ng-class="{'selected': selectedLink === 'Service'}">
            <h1>Services</h1>
            <label>Provide a Service</label>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.selected { color: yellow; }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

```
<a ng-click='addType("Physical"); visited = true' ng-class="{'visited' : visited}" href="javascript:void(0);"></a>
```

Comment: I have already used it, but :visited psuedo class is not working for me. This does not redirect to anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

```
 <div id="Navigation" class="md-dialog-full">
     <div class="products-options">
         <a ng-click='addType("Physical")' href="javascript:void(0);" class="{selectedPhysical}">
             <h1>Physical</h1>
             <label>An item that is shipped to your customers</label>
         </a>
         <a ng-click='addType("Digital")' href="javascript:void(0);" class="{selectedDigital}">
             <h1>Digital</h1>
             <label>Content that is downloaded</label>
         </a>
         <a ng-click='addType("Service")' href="javascript:void(0);" class="{selectedService}">
             <h1>Services</h1>
             <label>Provide a Service</label>
         </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

in your controller

```
$scope.addType = function(type){
  if(type == 'Physical'){
   $scope.selectedPhysical = 'selectedLink'
   $scope.selectedDigital = ''
   $scope.selectedService = ''
   }
  else if(type == 'Digital'){
    $scope.selectedDigital = 'selectedLink'
    $scope.selectedService = ''
    $scope.selectedPhysical = ''
  }
  else{
    $scope.selectedService = 'selectedLink'
    $scope.selectedDigital = ''
    $scope.selectedPhysical = ''
  }
}
```

add css for `selectedLink`

```
.selectedLink{
  color : Blue;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  //whatever the changes you want to made for the active link text
 }
```

If you are using this you can overwrite the browser **Active** pseudo class