# Highlight current menu using AngularJS

Tags: jquery, angularjs, bootstrap-4

I am using the following code:

```
<li class="sidebar-list-item"><a ng-class="getClass('/dashboardHome')" href="/dashboardHome" class="sidebar-link text-muted"><i class="o-home-1 mr-3 text-gray"></i><span>Home</span></a></li>


$scope.getClass = function (path) {
        console.log("Path: "+path);
        return ($location.path().substr(0, path.length) === path) ? 'active' : '';
      }
```

On console I am getting : Path: /dashboardHome

But not its not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do like this if you use `ui-sref`.

```
ui-sref-active="active" ui-sref="home.dashboard.dashboardHome"
```

You do not need to use `ng-class` and getClass function.

## Update

ui-sref-active-eq:

> The ui-sref-active-eq directive applies the CSS class when the
>   ui-sref/ui-state's target state is directly active (not when child
>   states are active). This is an "exact match" which uses
>   StateService.is. -[ui-router.github.io](https://ui-router.github.io/ng1/docs/1.0.0/modules/directives.html)

If you do not want to activate the `parent` route when a child route is active, use `ui-sref-active-eq="active"` for the parent route.